# Having trouble accessing an array outside a loop in node

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am trying to load a list from psql and then pass it to and ejs template. I'm fairly confident that this is a result of the async nature of the code executing, it's creating the variable, fills it up, but then when we're out of the loop it's looking at the naked variable.

accountList is returning [] when I log outside of the loop. How do I make accountList available outside of the loop so I can send it to the ejs file?

```
const pool = new pg.Pool(config);

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {

    //query the database
    const query = {
        name: "getDB",
        text: "select * from smartsneakers",
    }

    //init the accountList to store information
    var accountList = [];
      
    pool.query(query, (err,res) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({"status_code": 500, "status_message": "internal server error"});
        } else {
                //loop to check each row
                for (let i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                    accountList.push(res.rows[i]);
                    //console.log(accountList)
                }
        } 
    });


    //console.log(accountList); will return [] at this level

    //close connection
    pool.end();

    //render the page
    res.render("ejs/index", {
        title: "campaign management",
        account: accountList, 
    });
});
 
var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on port', 3000);
});
```

Comment: Someone post the dupe close pls; I’m on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it returns with `promise` so you should write your `render` after the query ends like this

```
pool
  .connect()
  .then(client => {
    return client
      .query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1', [1])
      .then(res => {
        client.release()
        // you could add you render here
        
      })
      .catch(err => {
        client.release()
        console.log(err.stack)
      })
  })
```

you can read more in the [docs](https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling)